# Setting positional accessibility information on a ToolStripItem menu item

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, accessibility

In my application, I use a [`ContextMenuStrip`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.contextmenustrip?view=netframework-3.5) populated with [`ToolStripItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstripitem?view=netframework-3.5) to render a simple options menu in the program's UI. I'm trying to make my application as accessible as possible, and one thing I'm looking at is adding positional information to the menu options. For example, when the user tab selects the first menu item with a screen reader (NVDA, Narrator, JAWS etc) turned on, the screenreader should read something like "menu item 1, 1 of 3", assuming there are three menu items.

I've been able to change a few things that the screen reader reads on each menu item out by playing with the "Accessibility___" properties on the `ToolStripItem` instance I use to populate the menu, e.g. the [`AccessibleName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstripitem.accessiblename?view=netframework-3.5) property. However, I'm not able to see anything that would allow me to add positional accessibility information that would describe relative position in the menu list. I thought perhaps I could do something with the [`AccessibilityObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstripitem.accessibilityobject?view=netframework-3.5) attached to the `ToolStripItem`, but I'm just starting out on accessibility stuff and I'm not really sure. Any thoughts?

Comment: You *could* handle the MouseEnter/MouseLeave events of the ToolStripMenuItems (just one event handler for all), get the current Item (`var item = sender as ToolStripMenuItem;`), get the items count of the Owner (`int count = item.Owner.Items.Count;`), get the index of the current Item (`int index = item.Owner.Items.IndexOf(item) + 1;`) and set the `ToolStripMenuItem.AccessibleDescription`: `string content = $"Menu Item {index}, {index} of {count}"; item.AccessibleDescription = content;`. Clear on MouseLeave.

Comment: That's a good idea, I'll have to figure out how to get localized strings in there, but I'll see if I can make that idea work. Thanks!